# window.onload Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

There are many other questions on this error, and I've read many of them, but I still don't see what I am doing wrong here.

```
window.onload = function getProgram() {
    var prog_name = document.URL.split('=')[2];
    console.log(prog_name); //this outputs correctly
    document.getElementByID("program_name").innerHTML = "Program: " + prog_name;
    return true;
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       getProgram

Here is the html for the object that I am trying to update:

```
<div id="program_name"><label></label></div>
```

Comment: Not a specialist in javascript but wouldn't `window.onload` need a anonymous function... something like `window.onload = function(){//code goes here}`

Comment: It is already "anonymous" he is just giving it a name. A name helps for logging purposes.

Comment: @Sebastien - It's usually better to give functions a name so you can reference it later if you need it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 and true, Thanks guys for pointing that out didn't knew. I'll be less stupid tomorrow!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`.  I'm not sure that's the only problem, but it surely is *a* problem.

Comment: Aughhh! Thanks. Can't believe I missed that. I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: I teach JS and see that error all the time.  One's fingers want to type `ID`.